# Generate new table from a current table in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have sample table like this:

```
ID | 1 | 2 | 3
-------------
1  | 0 | 1 | 0
--------------
2  | 1 | 1 | 1
```

Then I want to generate a new table from that table. It will take the second row (1) then compare with each column (1, 2, 3) then print value of the matrix ( 0 - 1 - 0 ). For example:

```
Row_ID | Column_ID | Value
--------------------------
1      | 1         | 0
--------------------------
1      | 2         | 1
--------------------------
1      | 3         | 0
--------------------------
2      | 1         | 1
--------------------------
2      | 2         | 1
--------------------------
2      | 3         | 1
```

I'm not sure how or where to start by using formula. Please help. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. There's no single formula that's going to do the job, obviously, but we have a few options we can use.  I'll assume that the new table is going to start in cell A1 of Sheet2. Adjust accordingly.

Start with manually entered headers
`Row_ID | Column_ID | Value`

In the first column, first row, enter a 1. In rows below, use this formula: `=IF(B3<B2,A2+1,A2)` This will increment the value in the first column by 1 each time the second column resets its numbering.

In the second column, first row, enter a 1. The formula we'll use for this one will need some tweaking, but the basic version is: `=IF(MOD(ROW()**+1**,**3**)=0,1,B2+1)`

This formula is going to essentially count up to a certain point, then reset its numbering. The point it will count to, and where it will reset, will vary depending on the amount of data you have and which row you're starting from.  Replace the **3** with the number of data columns you have, and remove the **s. The +1 is needed to increase the Row() counter to the SAME NUMBER as your number of data columns. So in my example, with 3 data columns and starting on row 2, the ROW() function gives us 2, so we need to add 1 to that to get up to a total of 3. If I had 5 data columns, I would add 3 to the total. Hope that makes sense.

These two formulae should give you a set of row and column numbers. Copying the formula down will force the values to increase as needed, thus:

```
Row_ID | Column_ID | Value
   1   |     1     |
   1   |     2     |
   1   |     3     |
   2   |     1     |
```

...etc.

Finally, to bring in the values, we'll use an `OFFSET` formula in the Value column: `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,A2,B2)` That formula starts from a reference cell - A1, in this case - then moves down x number of rows and across y number of columns to return a value. X and Y are provided by the formulas we already have.  Your final structure will be something like this:

```
Row_ID | Column_ID | Value
   1   |     1     |=OFFSET(...
=IF(...|=IF(MOD(...|=OFFSET(...
```

I hope all that made sense. Please let me know if there's anything that doesn't, and I'll try to troubleshoot.

EDITED TO ADD:
If the Row ID is something like a key that needs to be included with each value, we can get that fairly easily. We'll include another column with a slightly modified OFFSET formula: `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,A2,0)`

With this version of the formula we're not changing the column as we go down, just the row when it changes. It allows the values in the first row to be repeated in every row of the table. So this is my input:

[image: This is my test input]

And this is my output:

[image: And this is my output]

Notice that the ID repeats on each line of the output for the same item.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I have question about step one. The table is not really incremental. The number and value could be different and randomly. For example: 1,2,5,10,13... Is there any ways that we can improve the first formula? =IF(B3<B2,A2+1,A2)

Comment: If I'm following correctly, the `Row_ID` in your example is something like an identifier, rather than a simple indicator of where in the table that value is, and thus it should be repeated on each row of our new table that pulls from that data row - is that correct? If so, yes, we can include that as well. We won't change the first formula, though - I'll edit the answer to include this step.

Comment: Thank @Werrf. I'm consuming your idea. Looks like it really works! In the column_id, can it be shown as Value 1, Value 2 and Value 3 instead of id number?

Comment: The number is what it's using to find which column the data is coming from. If you want to include the Value 1, Value 2 and Value 3 as well, you can do the same thing we did to bring across the ID, but make the column absolute, ie: `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,B2).` Put that in another column so you have something like `Row | Column | Row ID | Column ID | Value`

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're the best!